# Custom implementation of NMS in pure tensorflow (Using Fasterrcnn for point detection)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Context of the Problem Trying to Solve:

I am using FasterRcnn to detect key points. And I am stuck at the implementation of custom NMS in tensorflow. I can't use tensorflow's NMS as it is for bounding boxes and I want to implement it for keypoint detection based on Euclidean distance as a parameter.

I saw view github repos were they implemented custom NMS but in caffe not tensorflow:
https://github.com/msracver/Deformable-ConvNets

https://github.com/kevinjliang/tf-Faster-RCNN

So my question: is it possible to implement custom NMS for proposals from rpn layer to rcnn layer in pure tensorflow?

I want to write the whole NMS operation in tensorflow, the point where I am stuck at is accessing the individual index for NMS logic without sess.run().

PS: I don't know CUDA programming, to edit .cu files mentioned in the above repos.
Let me know if more details are needed.